# Como sumarle una lista a una variable que contiene una lista y el resultado usarlo como lista para extraer datos de un dataframe con "at"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

En la variable `MARCADOR`, `LAD` y `FAD` me gustaría extraer con cada ciclo `for` datos del `DataFrame intersection`:

```
INCREMENTO = np.array([0, 0])

for x in range(self.total_rows):

    MARCADOR = self.intersection.at([0, 0] + INCREMENTO)
    LAD = self.intersection.at([0, 2] + INCREMENTO)
    FAD = self.intersection.at([0, 1] + INCREMENTO)

    INCREMENTO = INCREMENTO + [1, 0]
```

Por ejemplo, en el segundo ciclo `for` para la variable `MARCADOR` necesitaria extraer el dato `[1,0]` y para el tercero el `[2,0]` y asi sucesivamente pero no conozco la sintaxis para sumarle una variable con una lista a otra lista que extrae el dato a un `dataframe` con `at`.

La idea es ir ploteando `MARCADOR`, `FAD` y `LAD` en cada ciclo `for`.

Por favor enseñenme como hacerlo o indicandome en donde debo buscar.

Comment: Si quieres iterar fila a fila sobre el DataFrame puedes usar [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows). `for index, row in self.intersection.iterrows(): marcador = row[0]; lad = row[2]; fad = row[1]`. En principio no hay necesidad de usar el array INCREMENTO para nada.

Comment: Sería más simple entender cual es tu objetivo final si agregas un ejemplo de DataFrame y que quieres obtener en cada iteración. Por otra parte si explicas qué gráfico quieres generar es muy posible que exista una mejor solución mucho más simple y sin iterar explícitamente, Pandas permite generar multitud de gráficos a partir de un DataFrame de forma simple y directa usando Matplotlib como backend.

Comment: Muchas Gracias FJSevilla por su tiempo y conocimiento !!!